# Windows 7 Taskbar Not Hiding in Full Screen

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, nvidia-graphics-card, fullscreen

This a weird issue I've been dealing with for a while.  Whenever I watch a video in full screen, the taskbar stays on top of the video.  I can force it to hide by doing the following in this order:

```
 1. Exit fullscreen
 2. Click show desktop on the taskbar (minimizing all windows)
 3. Click show desktop on the taskbar (maximizing all windows)
 4. Re-enter fullscreen
```

I have an Nvidia graphics card, with the current driver.  The OS is fully up to date.

I currently have the taskbar set to auto-hide as a work-around but would prefer to have an actual solution.  Has anybody run into this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recently started having this problem in Windows 10.

The solution is to restart `explorer.exe`:

1. Open **Task Manager** (Ctrl+Shift+Esc)
2. Select **Windows Explorer** from the list
3. Click the **Restart** button

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Rab also worked for me. After uninstalling, I did not reboot, and the full screen started working properly.

Comment: This is good information. That said, this might be better as a comment attached to the original answer that worked rather than as an answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

Do a clean boot(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) and check if it is gone, if gone then re enable one service and restart pc, check for problem. Do this while you find service responsible for problem. For me the solution was to disable Geforce experience on startup or uninstall it.